# Polar form of 2D Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider two independent unidimensional Brownian motion $w_1$ and $w_2$.
What is the polar form of $(w_1,w_2)$?

If $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ satisfy $(w_1,w_2) = r(t)(\cos(\phi(t)),\sin(\phi(t)))$, how to get an equation for $\phi$?

The equation for $r(t)$ can easily be obtained using Ito’s rule, that is
$$
d r(t) = \frac{1}{r(t)} d t + d \tilde w(t).
$$
where $\tilde w$ is a Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

You have $d\varphi(t)=\frac{1}{r(t)}d\check{w}_t$, where $\check{w}_t$ is another Brownian motion, independent of $\tilde{w}_t$. This can be calculated, e.g., by applying Ito's formula to $\varphi=\arctan(w_2/w_1).$ Perhaps an even easier way is to start with these $r(t),\varphi(t)$ and check that $r(t)\cos\varphi(t)$ and $r(t)\sin\varphi(t)$ are independent Brownian motions.

An even simpler way is to use the theory of Markov processes, i.e., view this process as a Markov process with generator $\Delta=\partial^2_x+\partial^2_y,$ which in polar coordinates is $\frac{1}{r}\partial^2_\varphi+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\partial^2_r.$

Comment: Since the codomain of arctan is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, it seems to me that some information gets lost. I’ll use the generator. Thanks.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, a square is missing in front of the second order partial derivative w.r.t. $\varphi$.